# Python: TypeError: numpy.float64

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, typeerror, multiplication

I defined the following matrix:

`B = np.outer(v,n1) + W`

Which means:

B = v^T * n1 + W.

W is a matrix with s columns and rows respectively.
The vector n1 has s elements, as well as the transposed vector v.
Thus, if you multiply v and n1 with each other (using the np.outer command) you receive a matrix.

I wanted to calculate

`B[1][1]*1`

So the entry in the 1st row and 1st column of B.

However I received the following error:

`TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'numpy.float64'`

And the thing is, I did ensure that the matrix B consists of integers only.

What do I have to change? I did some research, and the only thing I could find is that I have to ensure that I have to work with integers rather than floats (I think)

Comment: Can you please `print(n1)` and `print(W)` and show us?

Comment: full error message please.  What's the `sequence` (list?) it's talking about?

Comment: The error message is telling you that something like `[1,2,3]*3.4` does not work.  "multiply` for a 'sequence' means 'repeat'.  You probably meant to multiply an array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make sure every variable is of the type (np.array) and dimension you are expecting. I have tried with my own variables and I don't obtain any error. Maybe if you share your code it would be easier for me to help.

Also it could be you are not really obtaining the first element when you put B[1][1]. At first because the index starts at 0, and also because it depends on if the element B is a np matrix or an np array.

If you share the complete code I would be delighted to help you